# Android create single service instance for Socket.io

Tags: android, sockets

in my application i cant create simple single service to connect to Socket, in my application after first run application i can emmit one request, but after close application and run again, my app send twice request to socket.io, and after clear app from recent application, that send multiple request to socket.io. please help me to create single service to create one connection, Thanks

My Service:

```
public class SignalChatServiceProvider extends Service {
    public static      SignalChatServiceProvider instance                    = null;

    public static boolean isInstanceCreated() {
        return instance == null ? false : true;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return myBinder;
    }

    private final IBinder myBinder = new LocalBinder();

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public SignalChatServiceProvider getService() {
            return SignalChatServiceProvider.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        signalApplication = (SignalApplication) getApplication();
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        connectConnection();
        Log.e("EJRA...", "");
        return START_STICKY;
    }


    private Runnable onTypingTimeout = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

        }
    };

    private void connectConnection() {

        instance = this;
        signalApplication.CHAT_SOCKET = signalApplication.getSocket();
        signalApplication.getSocket().on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, onConnectError);
        signalApplication.getSocket().on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, onConnectError);
        signalApplication.getSocket().on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, onConnect);

        signalApplication.getSocket().on("new message", onNewMessage);
        signalApplication.getSocket().on("user joined", onUserJoined);
        signalApplication.getSocket().on("getProductImages", getProductImages);

        signalApplication.getSocket().connect();
    }

    private void disconnectConnection() {
        instance = null;

        signalApplication.getSocket().disconnect();

        signalApplication.getSocket().off(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, onConnect);
        signalApplication.getSocket().off(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, onDisconnect);
        signalApplication.getSocket().off(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, onConnectError);
        signalApplication.getSocket().off(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, onConnectError);
        signalApplication.getSocket().off("new message", onNewMessage);
        signalApplication.getSocket().off("user joined", onUserJoined);
        signalApplication.getSocket().off("getProductImages", getProductImages);

        signalApplication.getSocket().disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        disconnectConnection();

        if (!realm.isClosed())
            realm.close();
    }
}
```

ActivityMain:

```
if (signalApplication.getSocket() != null && !SignalChatServiceProvider.isInstanceCreated()) {
    startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), SignalChatServiceProvider.class));
}
```

Application class:

```
public class SignalApplication extends Application {

    public static List<MarketsBaseInformation> market_list_cache_data;
    public static Socket                       CHAT_SOCKET;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        resources = this.getResources();
        context = getApplicationContext();

        IO.Options opts = new IO.Options();
        opts.forceNew = true;
        opts.reconnection = true;

        try {
            CHAT_SOCKET = IO.socket(ClientSettings.getChatAddress(), opts);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("SOCKET.IO ", e.getMessage());
        }


    }

    public Socket getSocket() {
        return CHAT_SOCKET;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Tux-world,

In your service, can you add a log inside the onCreate and onDestroy methods and when you go through this cycle of starting / stopping your application, how many times do you see these logs appear?

Comment: @Henrik Gyllensvärd Hi sir, after clear application from recent applications, my service created again,in fresh install and openning application, send request is `once`, after open application on MainActivity request is `twice`, why? i'm tired :(

Comment: I'm trying to help, but to give a clear and good answer I asked about the logs :)

You can also try this, in your MainActivity, override the onDestroy method so and add this:

stopService(new Intent(this, SignalChatServiceProvider.class));

If this helps we should restructure your code a bit to improve how this is done. :)

Comment: Hi, thanks. My problem resolved sir.please let me to reply to my post. :)

Comment: Sorry, just to confirm, you mean you want to write the answer to the question yourself here and mark it as solved?

Even though this solves the matter, the comment and stopping the Service doesn't really explain why this happens for you. Also there are in my view better ways of using the Service class that I can include in an answer if you want. :)

Comment: No problem sir. I post solution. Please review that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Problem resolved**

```
public class SignalChatServiceProvider extends Service {
    public static       SignalChatServiceProvider instance         = null;
    public static final String                    GET_COMMANDS     = "onGetCommands";
    public static final String                    NEW_REGISTRATION = "onNewRegistration";

    private SignalApplication signalApplication;
    private Realm             realm;
    private String            marketUUid;

    public static boolean isInstanceCreated() {
        return instance == null ? false : true;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return myBinder;
    }

    private final IBinder myBinder = new LocalBinder();

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public SignalChatServiceProvider getService() {
            return SignalChatServiceProvider.this;
        }
    }

    public void IsBendable() {
        //Toast.makeText(this, "I bind like butter", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        //@formatter:on
        if (isInstanceCreated()) {
            return;
        }
        super.onCreate();
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

        signalApplication = (SignalApplication) getApplication();

        if (signalApplication.getSocket() == null)
            signalApplication.CHAT_SOCKET = signalApplication.getSocket();

        signalApplication.getSocket().on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, onConnectError);
        signalApplication.getSocket().on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, onConnectError);
        signalApplication.getSocket().on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, onConnect);

        //@formatter:off
            signalApplication.getSocket().on("get commands"        , onGetCommands);
            signalApplication.getSocket().on("getMarketBanners"    , getMarketBanners);
            signalApplication.getSocket().on("getMarketProducts"   , getMarketProducts);
            signalApplication.getSocket().on("getProductImages"    , getProductImages);
        //@formatter:on

        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        connectConnection();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private Emitter.Listener onConnect = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    EventBus.getDefault().post(
                            new SignalChangeChatServerStateEvent(SignalChangeChatServerStateEvent.chatServerState.connected)
                    );
                }
            });
        }
    };

    private Emitter.Listener onDisconnect = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    EventBus.getDefault().post(
                            new SignalChangeChatServerStateEvent(SignalChangeChatServerStateEvent.chatServerState.disconnected)
                    );
                }
            });
        }
    };

    private Emitter.Listener onConnectError = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    EventBus.getDefault().post(
                            new SignalChangeChatServerStateEvent(SignalChangeChatServerStateEvent.chatServerState.flashConnectionIcon)
                    );
                }
            });
        }
    };

    private Emitter.Listener onGetCommands = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Object... args) {
        }
    };

private Emitter.Listener getMarketBanners = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Object... args) {
        }
    };

    private Emitter.Listener getProductImages = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Object... args) {
        }
    };

    private Emitter.Listener getMarketProducts = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Object... args) {
        }
    };

    private void connectConnection() {
        instance = this;
        signalApplication.getSocket().connect();
    }

    private void disconnectConnection() {
        instance = null;
        signalApplication.getSocket().disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (!realm.isClosed())
            realm.close();

        signalApplication.getSocket().off(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, onConnect);
        signalApplication.getSocket().off(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, onDisconnect);
        signalApplication.getSocket().off(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, onConnectError);
        signalApplication.getSocket().off(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, onConnectError);

        //@formatter:off
            signalApplication.getSocket().off("get commands"        , onGetCommands);
            signalApplication.getSocket().off("getMarketBanners"    , getMarketBanners);
            signalApplication.getSocket().off("getMarketProducts"   , getMarketProducts);
            signalApplication.getSocket().off("getProductImages"    , getProductImages);
        //@formatter:on

        disconnectConnection();
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onEvent(SignalChangeChatServerStateEvent event) {
        switch (event.getState()) {
            case connected:
                connectConnection();
                break;
            case disconnected:
                disconnectConnection();
                break;
        }

    }
}
```